# Spring Boot does not support hikari keepaliveTime configuration

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Can you please let us know how can I can pass keepaliveTime config to Hikari in spring boot 2.1.12

Comment: Does `spring.datasource.hikari.keepaliveTime=30000` in your application.properties not work?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be setter called `setKeepaliveTime` on the DataSource object[see docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/latest/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html#setKeepaliveTime(long))

There is an article on how to configure datasource configurations specifically for sping boot [here](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikari/)